# Wrong encoding after URL decoding on Wildfly 10 with JSF and Omnifaces

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, url-encoding, wildfly-10, omnifaces

I have a simple JEE 7 application, running on Wildfly 10.1.0.Final, with an encoding problem after URL decoding.

I am using the `org.omnifaces.util.FacesLocal` class from Omnifaces 2.6.3 to redirect to another page with additional GET parameters as part of the URL, e.g. `/<context-root>/search.xhtml?topic=1&term=Österreich`

The redirect is working as expected and the URL seems to be correctly URL encoded. `/<context-root>/search.xhtml?topic=1&term=%D6sterreich`

The URL encoding happens internally in the `org.omnifaces.util.Utils` class, by using UTF-8 as encoding.

```
public static String encodeURL(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(string, UTF_8.name());
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING, e);
    }
}
```

After the redirect I am trying to access the GET parameter from the `ExternalContext`, but the encoding seems to be broken. For the given example I get `?sterreich` as string.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

// Delivers the GET-parmeter with broken encoding
String term = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("term");

// Delivers the complete query string with correct encoding
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
String queryString = servletRequest.getQueryString();
```

I already checked the following encodings.

Platform encoding is: UTF-8

Wildlfy encodings are also set to: UTF-8

```
<servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8">

<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" url-encoding="UTF-8" />
```

I also tried adding the Omnifaces CharacterEncodingFilter to web.xml to set the request character encoding to UTF-8.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

What encoding setting am I missing?

Is it possible that Undertow is falling back to ISO_8859_1?

---

After some more digging I found out that the problem seems to be the encoding part and not the decoding one.

For testing I set the url-charset to ISO-8859-1 (via standalone.xml) and everything was working as expected.

`<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" decode-url="true" url-charset="ISO-8859-1" />`

After this finding I re-checked the code that is responsible for the encoding and found out that the URL is no longer encoded by the Omnifaces Utils method, that I mentioned previously (another developer rewrote the code). Therefore I testet it again by manually encoding the URL with UTF-8 charset and received a new URL that is now correctly UTF-8 encoded.

`/<context-root>/search.xhtml?topic=1&term=%C3%96sterreich`

To fully understand the issue I have the following open questions:

- Who is responsible for automatic URL encoding, if it's not done by me? Is it JSF or Undertow?
- Where can I change the encoding, that is used for the encoding?

If there is no solution I will correctly encode the URL by myself but it would be nice if the automatic way (thats already happening somewhere) would also work correctly.